# Javascript Timer Issues

Tags: javascript, timer

I am setting up a timer on an array of dynamic data taken from a db. It works but when I click the button for a second time it makes the seconds increment really quickly.  I would also like to set the initial count back to 60 each time the button is clicked. Can anyone help?   My code so far is as follows:

```
<script>
  var counts = [];
  var xs = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 61; i++) {
        counts.push(61);
        xs.push(0);
    };


    function timer(id) {           
        xs[id] = setTimeout("timer(" + id + ")", 1000);
        counts[id] = counts[id] - 1;
        if (counts[id] < 1) { counts[id] = 0; }
        document.getElementById("but" + id).innerHTML = counts[id];

    }

           function restarttimer(id) {           
        xs[id] = setTimeout("timer(" + id + ")", 1000);
        counts[id] = counts[id] - 1;
        if (counts[id] < 1) { counts[id] = 0; }
        document.getElementById("but" + id).value = counts[id];

    }


</script>


<?php

$i=1;
?>
<table id="itemTable"><tr>
  <?php
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($resultSearch))
{
    ?>


<td>

    <p id="but<?php echo $r['itemID'];?>">>
    </p>

      <input type="button" value="bid" onclick="timer(<?php echo $r['itemID'];?>)" />



  </td>
<?php
    if($i % 3 == 0)
            echo '</tr><tr>';
   $i++;
}
```

?>

Comment: Consider using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` for this kind of things, and a function instead of a string as the argument.

Comment: *"Javascript Java Timer Issues"* This question has nothing to do with Java. Java != JavaScript. I've corrected the title for you.

Comment: Thank you I have not idea why I typed that in as the header.

Comment: I have now sorted this but am not able to post my solution for another 8 hours.